# How to give command line option in java program?

Tags: java, command-line, jfr, commercial-application

I want to use Java flight recorder while running my java program. Can I pass arguments in java program itself and not while running the application.

For ex: I have a java class say "HelloWorld.class" I want to use java flight recorder while running this which i can achieve with

> java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder HelloWorld

But I want to achieve this unlocking commercial feature and start flight recorder from my java code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should only do this if you have a commercial license from Oracle, and you should not put it into library code, so others by mistake unlocks it in production without their knowledge.

At runtime, it's probably easiest to do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + pid + " VM.unlock_commercial_features");
```

In JDK 9 or later, you can get the pid from ProcessHandle;

```
ProcessHandle.current().pid()
```

In earlier releases, you can get the pid from RuntimeMXBean:

```
String jvmName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
int index = jvmName.indexOf("@");
String pid = jvmName.substring(0, index);
```

Another alternative is to do it over JMX using DiagnosticCommandMXBean.

```
    ObjectName on = new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"); 
    Object[] a = new Object[] {
        new String[] {
        }
    };
    String[] sig = new String[] {"[Ljava.lang.String;"};
    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(on, "vmUnlockCommercialFeatures", a, sig);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Kire I tried this                                                            long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + pid + " VM.unlock_commercial_features");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + pid + " JFR.start");                                                   But its still complaining about unlocking commercial feature while running the program. I am using JDK 9.

Comment: I can't reproduce with JDK 9.0.1. Did "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + ProcessHandle.current().pid() + " VM.unlock_commercial_features");"

Comment: I have used 9.0.4 and these lines Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + ProcessHandle.current().pid() + " VM.unlock_commercial_features");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jcmd " + ProcessHandle.current().pid() + " JFR.start"); Its not giving any error on these lines but when I am trying to use jfr for some Recording its saying, it should be unlocked first.

Comment: Hod did you start the recording programmatically? I tried: Recording r = new Recording(Configuration.getConfiguration("default")); r.start()

Comment: I did like this

Comment: try (Recording recording = new Recording()) {
            recording.setName("MY Recording");
            
            recording.start();

Comment: I tried this as well try (Recording recording = new Recording(Configuration.getConfiguration("default"))) {
            recording.setName("MY Recording");
            
            recording.start();

Comment: Are you starting the program so it can run jcmd in the shell (i.e. JDK_HOME/bin)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192639/discussion-between-kire-haglin-and-schaturv).